# Do not want to display bars with null values in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

My bar chart currently leaves a space if the value in dataset is null

Is there any way i can extend the Bar chart to not show bar with null as value ?

I have a null value in dataset for march, which i dont want to occupy space in chart

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot here?

Comment: Have added screnshot

Comment: While passing value check if value is not null then suppy value as parameter.